# When to use an active filter instead of a passive filter?

Tags: filter

I want to build a low-pass or a band-reject filter to remove 50/60Hz humming noise. I couldn't decide where to start with. I will use this filter to remove 50Hz noise where I make data-acquisition of a signal through a BNC cable.

Active or passive filters both could be used but I don't know the trade-offs.

Comment: active filter requires power.  passive filter like yours (band-reject) will require an inductor.

Comment: what would be the advantage in this case to use an active filter?

Comment: you can make very sharp higher-order filters without coils.

Comment: frequency range sometimes below 10Hz sometimes up to 500Hz. band-reject seems a better option. but I couldnt deccide if it should be active or passive..

Comment: check this link there is an active lp filter: http://alignment.hep.brandeis.edu/Lab/Filter/Filter.gif What is the advantage of it to a passive low-pass RC filter conceptually?

Comment: no it was just a google search:-)

Comment: You could try a twin t passive RC filter if your load impedence is large compared to your source impedence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many digital sampling applications it is possible to remove mains noise by sampling the signal at twice mains frequency and averaging the result of each pair of samples.

[image]

The image shows hum superimposed on a steady signal. Each black 'x' is a sampling point and it should be reasonably obvious that sampling at any odd multiple of the half-wave time (every half-wave, every 3, every 5, etc.) will result in samples that alternate above or below or exactly on the signal. Averaging each pair of readings will eliminate the hum.

This approach is commonly used in industrial signal applications such as temperature controllers where a very low voltage signal is being measured and the sensor wires run in close proximity to mains cables.

If you were designing a product for the international market you may wish to make the sampling switchable between 50 and 60 Hz. Even better would be to pass a mains zero-cross signal from the PSU to the controller so that it automatically selected the right frequency.

Comment: No it doesnt work fir me. My sampling rates are 500 to 4000. Besides Im not after mean value of the signal, but dynamic response.

Comment: @user16307: maybe you should describe your application then... because I have the feeling this might be an [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) with all various stuff you've said (including the need to vary the filter's reject center frequency).

Comment: @user16307: And I don't know what "dynamic response" might mean. [Impluse response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_response)? If you low-pass at 60Hz, you won't be able to record anything faster (more dynamic) than that so your 400 to 5000sps won't help.

Comment: For this method to work satisfactory, you would have to somehow trigger your readings on the "hum clock". Otherwise the noise will always affect the signal, as the sample points will not be in sync with the inaccurate "hum" frequency. Alternatively you could sample the signal at a very high sample rate and determine each peak value of the sine wave. Anyway, all such solutions are simply not professional. The proper solution is of course to eliminate the noise from appearing on the data signals in the first place.

Comment: @Lundin, (1) the 'hum' frequency in very many applications is the mains frequency and that's what the answer addresses. (2) Sampling the peak of each wave will give the peak of the sine wave whereas we actually want the mean value. (3) Such solutions are very professional and based on sound engineering principles. (4) Eliminate noise where and as much as possible. Then apply techniques such as this. (5) I encourage you to read up on how data is extracted from deep space probe signals by repetitive transmission and analysis where S/N ratio appears hopeless. Fascinating stuff.

Comment: @Transistor any specific references to data extraction from space probes ?

Comment: Try http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1968SSRv....8..595H. By page 611 or so they seem to be getting into it but I'm not sure it has the info you require. I think I read about the technique in [Elektor](http://elektor.com) but that's by subscription.

Answer (score 1):

Active filters are generally best in low-frequency, small signal work (audio, ultrasound, DAQ, etal), where amplifiers are easier to get than inductors.  Passive filters are used at high frequences (RF), where inductors are easier to come by than amplifiers, and at high power levels (power audio, AC mains filtering), where the size of the inductor isn't a point of contention anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The main **advantage** of active filters (provided the operating frequencies allow the use of opamps) is the fact that inductors (coils) can be replaced by active RC circuits. In some cases, there is a direct replacement of the inductor (active inductor realization). However, in most cases it is the task of the inductor to enable conjugate-complex poles which is taken over by active RC circuits (Sallen-Key structures, multi-feedback, integrator-based filters,...).

Here are the most important **disadvantages** of passive inductors (coils): Weight, cost, volume, no simple tuning, availability of required values, mechanically sensitive, EMC-problems.

Answer (score 0):

For 50/60Hz filtering, a passive filter requires a *big* inductor so expensive. These actually were the goto solution before active components like amplifiers etc. became the cheaper alternative.

Regarding

> range sometimes below 10Hz sometimes up to 500Hz

I'm not totally sure what you mean by this, but if you want a tunable filter, then perhaps a switched capacitor filter might be the easiest because to tune it you just change its switching frequency (proportionally to the center frequency of the band-reject).

You can read more pros and cons of passive/active/switched-capacitor filters on pp. 17-20 of NatSeti/TI's [AN 779](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa224a/snoa224a.pdf).

Comment: inductors? I thought lowpass can be done by an RC ??

Comment: @user16307: it can but you're asking about notch/[band-stop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band-stop_filter) filer.

Comment: so do u recommend a active band-stop filter?